# Динамическое создание dbgrid столько раз, сколько нужно пользователю

Tags: delphi

Есть строка в бд (фио, дата и другие атрибуты). Понадобилось, к каждой строке, добавить двумерную(ые) таблицу(ы). Их может быть больше одной.
Вся проблема в том, что изначально не известно количество таблиц и по этой причине я не могу додуматься как это сделать.
Т.е. допустим: количество наименований = 3, открывается форма, выбирается наименование из комбобокса, заполняется таблица, жмется кнопка, допустим, "сохранить" и еще два раза повторяется все сначала для других наименований, либо все три таблицы открываются сразу на одной форме.

Comment: фреймы для этих целей есть

Comment: Любой компонент можно создать через метод класса Create. Для визуальных компонентов нужно задать parent (на чем отображать объект), размеры и сделать visible = True.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Напишите задание так, как оно вам было дано изначально.